# How to define a custom type with `px` suffix

Tags: typescript

I know how to define a `Position` type class:

```js
class Position {
  x: number = 0;
  y: number = 0;
}
```

But now I need to the `x` and `y` value is a integer with `px` as suffix like:

```js
const position = {
  x: '1px',
  y: '2px'
}
```

How can I define a type like this in TypeScript?

Comment: You can't. That would be a [dependent type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) which are not only not present in Typescript put you have to go waaaay outside the bounds of normal languages to find. Best known language with dependent types is probably [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org/). Just check the values at run-time.

Comment: @JaredSmith You absolutely don’t need dependent types to implement what OP wants — user-defined type literals are sufficient, and many modern languages offer them. All OP then has to do is write `1px` instead of `'1px'` and, as far as I understand the question, that would be fine. As a simple workaround, defining a constructor function `px` would probably a long way towards what OP wants to implement.

Comment: @KonradRudolph defining a px constructor would work fine, but AFAIK there's no type literals in Typescript. My answer is a fairly idiomatic JS/TS solution. One could use a sweet.js macro to implement the desired logic, but that's a lot of complexity overhead for a fairly trivial performance benefit.

Comment: TypeScript 4.1 introduces [template literals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#template-literal-types)! This type of thing is possible now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. That would be a [dependent type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) which are not only not present in Typescript put you have to go waaaay outside the bounds of normal languages to find. Best known language with dependent types is probably [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org/).

In terms of actually solving the problem, the best solution is probably something like this:

```
const VALID_XY_VAL = /^(-?\d+)px$/;

class Point {
  _x: number = 0;
  _y: number = 0;

  constructor(x: string, y: string) {
    // NOTE: not _x and _y, we want to invoke the
    // setters here
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  get x () {
    return `${this._x}px`;
  }

  get y () {
    return `${this._y}px`;
  }

  set x(xVal: string) {
    const num = xVal.match(VALID_XY_VAL);
    if (num === null) throw new Error('Invalid value');
    this._x = Number(num[1]);
  }

  set y(yVal: string) {
    const num = yVal.match(VALID_XY_VAL);
    if (num === null) throw new Error('Invalid value');
    this._y = Number(num[1]);
  }
}

const p = new Point('1px', '2px'); // Point<1, 2>
p.x; // '1px'
p.y; // '2px'
p.x = '5px'; // a-ok
p.y = '5ac3px'; // KABOOM! Error.
```

This stores the pixel value internally (and type-safely) as a number. It will throw at runtime if you try to set an invalid value.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=31&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAagQQDIEkAiB9AGgTQ4pGAXhgHoA9ACgFoB+AHQBMBqASgAcAPAElIG4AUAOAAbAIYQIMAAogAlmFgBvATBgZOALhhgArgFsARgFMATsRgAGQWowBPbXqNmL1oWtCQop3cCghTSi0YaFMFAHMAGhgHEO8I1hgVNTUoAAs5CAA6TgtOGxT0zKy7CzsCgF93GHDjWFzKROSU0zrdUzAYAANuJSLsjQquLsrq2thSxqTVFraO7t7+rPshzhGZqpmIOphOILgxEW1QhOmUmE9oHQM8g5Es-TEoYDTKAnRsPAJWArU5ADMYJQnMQiCQ9CIRIl0qYQAB3HTGBEAUVMsMCAHIUGAAG6HOSMGB4kS6YwYn4zVIZAa5EgAOQMJkCTgA2gBGAC6FLUmzU2wmlDsd2O8TA4SalIu4CuIJIQsODyeLzeyA+uHwyG5KQBQNlYOukOhaVhCLASJgqPRlCxuPxhOJpPJvxgS3sFgZzmZBnZXNGFSAA)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zwC6FO/1)

### EDIT

Altocumulus makes the case in the comments that the regex should be a read-only static member of the Point class. There are plusses and minuses to each approach: the static member follows the principle of least privilege but impedes reuse (e.g. for another class or function in the same file with pixel values). I think a declared-const module-level immutable (in any way that matters) value is sufficient, but YMMV.

```
class Point {
  private static readonly VALID_VALUE: RegExp = /.../
```

Comment: Further fine-tuning to better encapsulate things, `VALID_XY_VAL` could be a constant member of class `Point`: `private static readonly VALID_XY_VAL = /^(-?\d+)px$/;`.

Comment: @altocumulus eh, that may be overkill. It's declared const (can't reassign) and the regex literal isn't mutable in any way that matters. Or am I missing something?

Comment: One of the basic principles of OOP! Keep it as tight as possible; no need to polute the global namespace. You might want to change the way you check the values some time soon without any side-effects or anyone being affected by this or anyone even knowing you made the change. Just my two cents.

Comment: @altocumulus The Typescript compiler uses the ES 2015 module system. There's no global namespace pollution, and the regex isn't exported so any change (e.g. from regex to substring checking) would be invisible to importers except through the altered behavior of the setters (assuming it *is* altered). If this were in a library you wouldn't even need to recompile the calling code. I mostly come from an FP background, and hiding an immutable constant value inaccessible outside the module scope seems... unidiomatic? IDK.

Comment: @altocumulus I've added an edit about it to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use this approach:

```
type HeightUnit = '%' | 'px' | 'em' | 'vh';
type HeightProp = `${number}${HeightUnit}`
```

and result:

```
myHeight: HeightProp;
myHeight = '10px'  --- ok
myHeight = '10'  --- compilation error
```

See [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) for more info

Comment: You should also allow "0". Can be done like this:
type HeightProp = \`${number}${HeightUnit}\` | "0"

You should probably also allow all other valid css length units, such as "vmin", "rem", "pt", etc. 

There are quite a lot, though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Answer (score -1):

### Edit, reasoning of the answer

Some of you can think this is not the answer for given question. But reality is that we as developers are responsible for modeling our data structures. Questioner asks here very specific question about how to model `"{number}px"` type in typescript. **The answer is one - it is not possible**. But the question is like that because questioner thinks this kind of type is a solution for his problem, what is misleading. The real problem is how to represent in type system the 2D point with two numeric values x,y and the unit. And this can be achieved by simple `[number, number, 'px']`, where we say we want two numbers and our unit is static 'px'. This kind of structure is flexible and type safe. Using some regexp, classes with setters and getters with throwing exception has nothing to compilation step, but is complex runtime validation.

### Original answer:

Why you need a class for representing a pair. Using class for such simple construct is like killing a fly with a hammer. What you really need is simple pair + unit representation, which can be represented as tuple `[a, b, unit]` or record `{a:a, b:b, unit: unit}`. As others also pointed, there is no possibility to define type which have number with `'px'` suffix, but you can model this in many ways. Few propositions:

---

1.Proposition one - modeling with additional unit information

```
// modeling as 3-nd tuple
type Point = [number, number, string]
const point = [1,2,'px']

// modeling as key-value map 
type Point = {x: number, y: number, unit: string}
const point = {x:1,y:2,unit:'px'}
```

---

2.Modeling with strict unit type.
If we are sure that there will be strict unit like 'px', it can be define in type. To not repeat myself, I will show examples only in key-value map types.

```
type Point = {x: number, y: number, unit: 'px'} // unit property can be only px
const point = {x:1,y:2,unit:'px'}
```

Also we can create point constructor in order to avoid putting px by hand:

```
const createPoint = (x: number, y: number):Point => ({x,y,unit:'px'});
const point = createPoint(1,2) // {x:1,y:2,unit:'px'}
```

---

3.Modeling as pair of strings but with constructor
We can leave the type as pair of string but generate this by number constructor

```
type Point = {x: string, y: string}
const createPoint = (x: number, y: number):Point => ({x: x + 'px', y: y + 'px'});
const point = createPoint(1,2) // {x:'1px',y:'2px'}
```

---

4.Modeling as an object with special get functions

```
type Point = {values: () => {x: number, y: number}, pixels: () => {x: string, y: string}}
// below is using closure and stored in it arguments of createPoint function
const createPoint = (x:number, y:number): Point => ({
  values: () => ({x, y}),
  pixels: () => ({x: x + 'px', y: y + 'px'})
})
const point = createPoint(1,2);
point.values() // {x: 1, y: 2}
point.pixels() // {x: '1px', y: '2px'}
```

Comment: I agree that a class is almost certainly overkill for a 2d point (I'd just use a POJO with ints and an appropriate interface if it were me), I merely answered the question as asked. But I disagree that a class is the overkill for the logic the OP wishes to implement: it's readable, likely more performant, plays nice with Typescript's type system, etc. etc. As for the runtime checking, once you go stringly-typed your options are pretty limited (which is why I'd stick with numbers, but again, answered the question as asked).

Answer (score -2):

You can either define a type with numerical x and y properties, as you did, or you define another type which allows both numbers and strings.

```
class Position {
  x: number | string = 0;
  y: number | string = 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about how to constrain values of strings to only ones ending in 'px' statically at compile-time.